# Name to Ticker in Bloomberg Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bloomberg

I've searched for this question for a while thinking it may be a common inquiry, but unfortunately only found one asking the opposite.

I would like to get the proper ticker name of a company using Bloomberg in Excel.

For instance, is it possible to gain "IBM US Equity" via a formula using "INTL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP" as an input? If so, what would the formula look like?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [OpenFigi](https://openfigi.com/) - the open source Bloomberg symbology.  You can see [here](https://openfigi.com/search#!?simpleSearchString=INTL%20BUSINESS%20MACHINES%20CORP&marketSector=Equity) that "INTL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP" actually matches a lot of separate tickers.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Assuming you have an idea of the "universe" of companies, your best bet is probably to create a spreadsheet with the list of potential tickers, use a `BDP` to get the names and do a `VLOOKUP` or something similar.

For example if the universe is an index, you can use `BDS` on the `INDX_MEMBERS` (and `INDX_MEMBERS2` and `INDX_MEMBERS3` for larger indices) fields to get the list of tickers within that index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Bloomberg provides a service via API that is meant explicitly for this. The service is called `//blp/instruments` and there's no point in me giving an example of how to use it because one is provided as part of the API examples: `SecurityLookupExample.csproj`. The API can be downloaded here: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/. I ran their example on "INTL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP" and got back "IBM US" which is what you wanted.